# How do I put some space between buttons vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a bunch of buttons, like this

[image]

Here is the code

```css
<style>
    .button-container {
        width: 320px;
        background: #fff;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .btn {
        width: 150px;
        background: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 36px 36px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: medium;
        border-color: #A7D1E8;
    }

    .btn:hover {
        background: #eee;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
        <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
        <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
        <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
        <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
        <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. It seems the width property in `.btn` doesn't work, the width of the container is 320px and the width of the button is 150px, there should be 2 buttons in a row but the result is not as expected, why is that?
2. How do I put some space between buttons vertically?

Comment: 1. Width of button is 150px + 2 * 36px (paddings) = 222px, for apply it, you need remove <style> tags in snippet.
2. add to `.btn` `margin-bottom: 20px;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style tag in the style  side of your snippet is making your button container class not work and for your space use margin-bottom

```css
.button-container {
  width: 320px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.btn {
  width: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 36px 36px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: #A7D1E8;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
  <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
  <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
  <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
  <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
  <button class="btn">Fight Here</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, this way

```
.button-container {
     width: 320px;
     background: #fff;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
     column-gap: 1rem;
     row-gap: 1rem;
}
```